# Does Firestore TTL delete documents in subcollections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I [know](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) that in Firestore deleting a document doesn't delete its sub-collections.

Does this hold true for documents deleted by the newly added TTL policies? [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl) doesn't state either way.

Comment: It just deletes the documents in the collection given in TTL policy just like normal deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does explicitly state that this policy is defined for collection groups. A [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) refers to all of the documents in collections *with the same name*. Subcollections with different names do not participate in a collection group. So you can be sure, based on the documentation, that a TTL configuration does not apply to subcollections with different names than the collection group where you establish the policy.

Comment: Does this mean that TTL will only delete the documents inside a collection but not the sub-collections inside it?